# Spurious keys filter

Tags: keys, key-derivation

Is there any possible way to filter a key space in a crypto-system to get a set of keys that decrypts out a valid text (text that is in same language or readable)?

I tried a random approach and got certain set of keys but its not that appreciative to actually required text size

**code**

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
import base64, string, time, random
key = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits ) for i in       range(8))
obj1 = ARC4.new(key)
obj2 = ARC4.new(key)
text = 'abcdefgh'
cipher_text = base64.b64encode(obj1.encrypt(text))

decoded_text= obj2.decrypt(base64.b64decode(cipher_text))

Dict={}
count=0
valid = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits )
def test(s):
    return set(s).issubset(valid)

print; print 'plain text: ', text
print; print 'Actual key: ', key 
print; print 'Cipher text: ', cipher_text

timeout=time.time()+60
while time.time()< timeout:
   count+=1
   key = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits ) for i in range(8))
   obj2 = ARC4.new(key)
   decoded= obj2.decrypt(base64.b64decode(cipher_text))
   if test(decoded):
       Dict.update({'key: '+key : 'Valid Decrypted Text: '+decoded})
import pprint
print; print 'Analysis: '
pprint.pprint(Dict)
print;print 'Number of valid Decrypted Text: ', len(Dict)
print;print 'Total number of decryption performed: ', count
```

**Output:**

```
plain text:  abcdefgh

Actual key:  go6oMkCG

Cipher text:  JB1a3osG+es=

Analysis: 
{'key: 0UUvjzLw': 'Valid Decrypted Text: mzptBVo4',

 'key: 2beOXKN1': 'Valid Decrypted Text: Yhz3jIL8',

 'key: 3Eq7MKwu': 'Valid Decrypted Text: GA9BTdzy',

 'key: 3jUQPXs8': 'Valid Decrypted Text: 3gCa3KBG',

.

.

Number of valid Decrypted Text:  36

Total number of decryption performed:  2275140
```

Is there any better to sort out such keys. **Such keys may be valuable to strengthen cryptography by introducing confusion**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you looking for keys that would map a given plaintext to some ciphertext containing only printing characters? Or for keys that would map any plaintext consisting only of printing characters to a ciphertext consisting of only printing characters? What do you mean by “spurious keys” (are you sure you're using the right English word here?)? Are you using “confusion” in the technical sense, and if not what do you mean? Where does key derivation come in?

Comment: By spurious keys i mean incorrect keys and among incorrect keys i am searching for those incorrect keys  that maps a cipher text to decrypted text that looks like a proper text(lets say english text map to english text) so that deciding whether that key is incorrect will be a confusing job to cryptanalyst....

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like this http://www.technologyreview.com/news/523746/honey-encryption-will-bamboozle-attackers-with-fake-secrets/

Comment: Indeed, sounds like you want the work of Tom Ristenpart on 'honey encryption' or 'format transforming encryption' depending on the exact meaning of your question

Comment: @ceasif: Do you want the ciphertext to look like English, or incorrect decryptions to look like English?

Comment: Actually I am planning to initiate with analysing key space that can give valid decryption(text like) with respect to text characterstics and algorithms. Then I shall look forward if i can shape encrypted/decrypted texts look like normal text. This can help to create difficulty in analysing if the data over network is encrypted or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem. For a specific ciphertext, sure you could try a bunch of keys and output the couple that result in the type of plaintext you want. But what does this really get you? For a different ciphertext, likely these same keys will not result in the same type of plaintext you desire.

Recent work on [honey encryption](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/155) might be what you are really looking for. It is still very new, so it should not be used in a production system without understanding all the intricacies. The authors of the paper also provide some nice theoretical foundation for the area.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. Actually, I am doing research in this field and I am just trying to figure out the measure of such confusing factor in modern cryptosystems. But I am not getting perfect weapon to do that. I will go through your suggestions and will be grateful to have further more  suggestions to this topic :)

Comment: @ceasif good luck with your research. I hope you find this site useful in your research.